# Property does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<DatePicker> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> ...'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to use React with TypeScript and Material-UI's components. Unfortunately, I'm getting the errors like this:

> Property 'openToYearSelection' does not exist on type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
>   Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> ...'.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';

interface IState {
  birthday: any,
}

export default class SampleForm extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    const { record = {} } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      birthday: record.birthday || null,
    };
  }

  public birthdayPicker() {
    const { birthday } = this.state;

    return (
      <DatePicker
        defaultDate={birthday}
        hintText="Birthday"
        openToYearSelection={true}
      />
    );
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <form style={styles.root}>
        {this.header()}
        {this.firstName()}
        {this.lastName()}
        {this.birthdayPicker()}
        {this.phoneNumber()}
        {this.actionButtons()}
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

What's the right way to use Material-UI with TypeScript and React?

Comment: Are you using the `@types/material-ui` package? And is your material-ui  version on a 0.x version or on v1-beta?

Comment: Hi @CRice, I'm using @types/material-ui and I set material-ui to "^0.20.0". I tried to update @types/material-ui/index.d.ts file with properties (please take a look at my answer below). However, I guess it's kind of hardcoding and it's not an appropriate solution.

Comment: I think that solution is fine, I've done the same for many other packages. The @types/material-ui package definitely missing some of the properties, and I don't think you can externally augment that interface. FWIW, when material-ui v1 drops, the types will be included right in the repo (so no need for @types), and hopefully then should be kept up to date.

Comment: @CRice, sounds good! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try adding `// @ts-expect-error` above the line that is erroring

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this problem by adding missing properties to namespaces in
`node_modules/@types/material-ui/index.d.ts` file. It worked for me. I don't think that it's a good solution and I'm wondering if there're some better approaches.

```
namespace DatePicker {
    export interface DatePickerProps {
        defaultDate?: Date;
        disableYearSelection?: boolean;
        ..
```

Comment: you're right in that it isn't a good solution. I would add that it isn't even a solution. you cannot edit anything in node_modules and expect reproducible builds/behavior as it will get wiped for every `npm install`.

if you need a custom prop, you can use the spread operator. typescript does not check against this

`<Something {...{key: 'value'}} />`

Comment: @Simon even your suggestion is not working. i tried to pass props that way also.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a third party library you can add this above the line that is erroring out and it'll ignore the error and let you build:

```js
// @ts-expect-error
```